# Removing 3D shadows of a shape in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, shadows

[image: Circles in Illustrator]

How can I remove those shadows? I tried selecting them and removing them but it doesn't work. I just want the circles.

Comment: Not certain how anyone can answer this without seeing how the file is constructed. They have to be an object, or effect, or something.

Answer (score 1):

If for any reason you couldn't delete it, you can use a clipping mask to hide the shadow. First copy the circles you want to keep then paste on top of the original graphic. Next use pathfinder merge those circles, so they are one path. Finally, select the merged path and the original graphic then create clipping mask. You should hide the shadow successfully. If nothing or just one circle is shown, double check these steps: 1. You have merged all the circles path. 2. The merged path is on top of the original graphic.